# CookieContainer from HttpWebRequest has path directly to file - How to ignoring path?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, session-cookies, httpwebresponse

i have a bug in my software because the C# HttpWebRequest is using the cookie of a domain only for the direct file.

For example:

Cookie `XYZ` with value `test` has path `/index.html` with domain `127.0.0.1`.

I want to use this cookie with path `/` for example.

How i can do this?

**Current method:**

```
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/index.html") as HttpWebRequest;
request.CookieContainer = cc;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
sr.Close();
response.Close();

// No cookies would be sent!
request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/informations.html") as HttpWebRequest;
request.CookieContainer = cc; // cc contains a cookie with path `/index.html` which wouldnt sent to informations.html
response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
sr.Close();
response.Close();
```

**Thank's in Advance!**

Comment: Changing the cookie path is up to the website / server software. Show us some code on how you set the cookie.

Comment: Uhm it's not my software. It's a software where i haven't the source. (Encrypted with IonCube) If there is no solution i read the cookie manually and set them manually again... :( The FireFox or Internet Explorer saves the cookies to correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along this way should work:
This code fills the cookie container with data received from the initial request. Cookies are set for the entire domain, on the root path, so they should get sent on every request.
Can you check?

```
    CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/index.html") as HttpWebRequest;
    //request.CookieContainer = cc;
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
    {
        Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, "/", "127.0.0.1");
        cc.Add(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1"), cookie);
    }

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
    sr.Close();
    response.Close();
```

Comment: Thats the new way i did ^^